# jQuery ajaxForm beforeSubmit fires on document.ready

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code:

```
$("#forma_mod_uid").livequery( function (){
       $("#forma_mod_uid").ajaxForm({
                beforeSubmit: mcargando("#cargando2"),
                target:'#mod_2',
                success: ocargando("#cargando2")
       })
});
```

The mcargando passes the div which will contain a spinner img, and then on success ocragando will hide that div, problem is that beforeSubmit is firing beforeSubmit on document ready.

```
function mcargando(id_div){
    if (id_div==null){ var id_div="#cargando";}
    $(id_div).livequery(function (){$(id_div).show();});
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
beforeSubmit: mcargando("#cargando2"),
```

Should be:

```
beforeSubmit: function() { mcargando("#cargando2") },
```

And

```
success: ocargando("#cargando2")
```

Should be:

```
success: function() { ocargando("#cargando2") }
```

As you have it right now, you *are* calling the functions. The only way you could use the code you have there without calling the function is if you did `beforeSubmit: mcargando,` but since you need to pass a variable to the function just wrap the call in a function to be able to do it and you should be fine.